# A simple javascript regex backreference

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

I have the following string that I am attempting to match:

```
REQS_HOME->31
```

The following Javascript code is attempting to match this:

```
pathRegExPattern = '(' + docTypeHome + ')' + '(->)' + '(\d+)';
parsedResult = pathCookieValue.match(pathRegExPattern);
cookieToDelete = docType + '_ScrollPos_' + $3;
alert(parsedResult);  // output - null
```

Assume the following:

```
docTypeHome = "REQS_HOME"
pathCookieValue = "REQS_HOME->31"
```

Firstly, I am not calling my match function properly.  And secondly, how do I access the value where I am attempting to match the digit values using the backreference operator?

I need to extract the value 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your digit-matching part needs to double-up on the backslashes:

```
pathRegExPattern = '(' + docTypeHome + ')' + '(->)' + '(\\d+)';
```

When you build up a regular expression from string parts, the string syntax itself will "eat" a backslash.  Thus, the regex you were winding up with was just `d+`, without the backslash.

The "31" (or whatever the number ends up being) will be in `parsedResult[3]`. Note that it'll be a string, so if you need it to be a number you'll want to convert it first, via the `Number` constructor, or `parseInt()`, or whatever.